# React-native: How Can we Use Load more based on ListView Calling Every 10 Records showing Spinner

Tags: listview, react-native

Developing Sample Application, I have an Issue in my Project calling Every 10 records in list view showing Spinner like Activity Indicator. My Problem was i have a Showed in list using List view Component I have a refresh list using Refresh Control in side List view Component. But I didn't know that how to Use pull down showing spinner for every 10 records.
Any one please show to me sample Demo with code.

This is my Code,

here the below method calling componentDidMount().

```
getNewOrders(){
        AsyncStorage.getItem('Data',(err,dataSource)=>{
      //  alert("dataSource:"+JSON.stringify(dataSource))
              var data=JSON.parse(dataSource)
              if(dataSource) {
                  this.setState({
                    asyncdataUrl: data.Url,
                    siteId:data.Keys.siteId
                  },()=>{
                    var str = this.state.asyncdataUrl;
                    str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');
                    str=str.replace("https","");
                    var siteId = this.state.siteId;
                  // alert("streee:"+str + this.state.siteId);
                     var value = 0;
                     this.state.value = value;
                               var string = {
                                            "from" : this.state.value, "size" : 10,
                                            "query": {
                                              "bool": {
                                                "filter": [
                                                    {
                                                      "match_phrase": {
                                                        "meta._customer_user.long" : this.state.tokenval
                                                      }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                      "match_phrase": {
                                                        "post_type" : "shop_order"
                                                      }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                      "terms": {
                                                        "post_status" : ["wc-processing", "wc-pending", "wc-on-hold"]
                                                      }
                                                    }
                                                  ],
                                                  "must_not": {
                                                    "match_phrase": {
                                                      "post_type" : "shop_order_refund"
                                                    }
                                                  },
                                                  "must": {
                                                    "match_all": {}
                                                  }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "_source": ["post_id", "post_type", "permalink", "post_status", "post_date", "post_excerpt", "post_site_data.*", "post_order_summary.*", "meta._customer_user.long", "meta._billing_first_name.value", "meta._billing_last_name.value", "post_line_items.*"],
                                            "sort": { "post_date": { "order": "desc" }}
                                        }


                        fetch('https://ori-eu-west-1.searchly.com/_all/_search',{
                         method:'POST',
                         headers:{
                           // 'Accept':'application/json',
                            'Content-Type':'application/json',
                            'Authorization': config.AuthorizationKey

                          },
                          body:JSON.stringify(string)
                      }).then((response)=>response.json()).then((responseData)=>{
                    //  alert("rowDatanewOrders:"+JSON.stringify(responseData.hits.hits[3]._source.post_line_items[0]))//._source.post_line_items[0]

                       if(responseData.status == 404 || responseData.hits.hits.length === 0) {
                           this.setState({animating:false})
                           //Alert.alert("", "No orders found")
                         }
                      else if(responseData.status == 'error'){
                                         this.setState({animating:false})
                           Alert.alert("", responseData.message)
                      }
                      else{
                        if(responseData.hits.hits.length <10){
                        //alert("rowDatanewOrders:"+JSON.stringify(responseData.hits.hits.length))
                        this.setState({
                          loadmore:'dontShow'
                        })
                       }
                       else if(responseData.hits.hits.length >=10){
                        this.setState({
                          loadmore:'false'
                        })

                       }
                           this.setState({
                            animating:false,
                           // loadmore:'false',
                            newOrderdataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.hits.hits),
                            NewOrdersdata:responseData.hits.hits
                           })
                         //  alert("value:"+this.state.NewOrdersdata[0])
                      }

                      }).catch((err)=>{
                          console.error(err)
                        })

                    })
                }
 }).done()
  }


  renderFooter(){
   // alert("dfdsfds")
    if(this.state.loadmore == 'true'){
      return(
      <ActivityIndicator
                   color = '#494949'
                   size = "large"
                   style = {{height:4}}
                   />)}
    else {
       return(
        <View></View>)
     }
  }

  onEndReachedNew(){
    // setTimeout(()=>{
            if(this.state.loadmore != 'dontShow'){
              this.setState({
              loadmore:'true'
            },()=>{
              // console.log("LodingData@@@@:" +this.state.loadmore)
                this.loadMoreData()
            })

         }
       // }, 3000)
       // this.setState({
       //     loadmore:'false'
       // })
    }
this is my ListView Component:
```

```
                                refreshControl={
                                  <RefreshControl
                                    refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                                    onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
                                  />
                                }
                                enableEmptySections ={true}
                                removeClippedSubviews={true}
                                dataSource={this.state.newOrderdataSource}
                                renderRow={this.listViewnewOrder.bind(this)}
                                renderFooter={this.renderFooter.bind(this)}
                                onEndReached = {this.onEndReachedNew.bind(this)}/>

loadMoreData(){
    this.setState({
    //  loadmore:'false',
      value:this.state.value+10
    },()=>{


                    var str = this.state.asyncdataUrl;
                    str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');
                    str=str.replace("https","");
                    var siteId = this.state.siteId;
                  // alert("streee:"+this.state.siteId +str);
                  //var value = 0;
                     // this.state.value = value;
                               var string =  {
                                            "from" : this.state.value, "size" : 10,
                                            "query": {
                                              "bool": {
                                                "filter": [
                                                    {
                                                      "match_phrase": {
                                                        "meta._customer_user.long" : this.state.tokenval
                                                      }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                      "match_phrase": {
                                                        "post_type" : "shop_order"
                                                      }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                      "terms": {
                                                        "post_status" : ["wc-processing", "wc-pending", "wc-on-hold"]
                                                      }
                                                    }
                                                  ],
                                                  "must_not": {
                                                    "match_phrase": {
                                                      "post_type" : "shop_order_refund"
                                                    }
                                                  },
                                                  "must": {
                                                    "match_all": {}
                                                  }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "_source": ["post_id", "post_type", "permalink", "post_status", "post_date", "post_excerpt", "post_site_data.*", "post_order_summary.*", "meta._customer_user.long", "meta._billing_first_name.value", "meta._billing_last_name.value", "post_line_items.*"],
                                            "sort": { "post_date": { "order": "desc" }}
                                        }
                        fetch('https://ori-eu-west-1.searchly.com/_all/_search',{
                         method:'POST',
                         headers:{
                           // 'Accept':'application/json',
                            'Content-Type':'application/json',
                            'Authorization': config.AuthorizationKey

                          },
                          body:JSON.stringify(string)
                      }).then((response)=>response.json()).then((responseData)=>{
                       // alert("responseData:"+JSON.stringify(responseData))

                       if(responseData == undefined){
                                  if(responseData.hits.hits.length == 0){
                                    this.setState({
                                      loadmore:'dontShow'
                                    })
                                  }
                                  else if(responseData.hits.hits.length <10){
                                     responseData.hits.hits.map((res)=>{
                                     this.state.NewOrdersdata.push(res)
                                   })
                                   this.setState({
                                     loadmore:'dontShow',
                                     newOrderdataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.NewOrdersdata),
                                   })
                                  }
                                  else{

                                     responseData.hits.hits.map((res)=>{
                                     this.state.NewOrdersdata.push(res)
                                   })
                                   this.setState({
                                     loadmore:'false',
                                     value:this.state.value+10,
                                     newOrderdataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.NewOrdersdata),
                                   })

                                  }

                           }

                        }).catch((err)=>{
                          console.error(err)
                        })


                         })


  }
```

Actually I am Calling two times Using my Function .I think this is wrong way calling because of there no Code Reusability. Please tell me how can i Call Showing Every time pulldown spinner adding 10 + records.